# npm install oracledb gyp ERR

Tags: node.js, oracle, npm, npm-install, gyp

If I attempt to install oracledb via npm, i get

> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit >(/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/>node-gyp/lib/configure.js:308:16)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.6.0
>
> gyp ERR! command "/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/bin/node" "/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd /Users//Documents/development/DB-Migration/node_modules/oracledb
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v7.7.3
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
>
> npm ERR! argv "/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/bin/node" "/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/bin/npm" "install" "oracledb"
>
> npm ERR! node v7.7.3
>
> npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! oracledb@1.13.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.13.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above."

I have updated but npm and node to the latest versions, so this is not the issue. 
I also attempted to install oracledb via instant client (https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instosx number 6)
    - when i try this, i get a " "errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node: invalid ELF header""

How can i install oracledb properly into my node project?

Comment: Overall your post lack any useful detail.  What do you mean "via Instant Client"?  On macOS you need the Instant Client.  From the ELF error, perhaps you got the wrong Instant Client, or forgot to rebuild node-oracledb.  Try cleaning up ("npm cache clean" etc) and follow the install instructions.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue in AIX while attempting to install node-oracledb. Somewhere along the line in the installation there is a `node-gyp rebuild` which is failing with `Exit Status 1`.